# Following code for loading shaders in openGL gives a heap corruption error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew

I am writing a function to parse shader code to c++ strings which openGL compiles.

```
ShaderSource LoadShaders(const string &filepath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filepath);

    enum class MODES
    {
        NONE = -1, VS = 0, FS = 1
    };



    string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    MODES mode = MODES::NONE;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != string::npos)
        {
            if (line.find("vertex") != string::npos)
                mode = MODES::VS;

            else if (line.find("fragment") != string::npos)
                mode = MODES::FS;
        }
        else
        {
            ss[(int)mode] << line << "\n";
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return { CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, ss[0].str().c_str()), 
             CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, ss[1].str().c_str()) };
}
```

I get heap corruption error after block #231 randomly on lines std::ifstream file(filepath);
to while loop.

Comment: What happens when `mode == MODE::NONE`? You need to protect against accessing that array out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You never check, that in

```
        ss[(int)mode] << line << "\n";
```

`mode` is a actually a valid value. You default initialize it to NONE which is -1. So if the first line of your shader file does not match the requirements to set a proper mode, you're going to end up writing out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the problem is that exception is thrown before that line and after continuing the app everything works fine until the end where I get debug error.

Comment: @Dragomir: This is happening in a loop, so in effect after the line *is* before the line. Unless you compiled with optimizations completely turned off there's a high probability that the sequence of lines doesn't reflect the actual execution order; compilers only have to assert that the eventual outcome, and the order of side effects is the same.